# What is the optimal amount of data for a table?

Tags: mysql

How much data should be in a table so that reading is optimal? Assuming that I have 3 fields varchar(25). This is in MySQL.

Comment: The snarky answer would be "none" - then reads would be ultra-quick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of rows should not matter.  Make sure the fields your searching on are indexed properly.  If you only have 3 varchar(25) fields, then you probably need to add a primary key that is not a varchar.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you consider the following in optimizing your database design:

1. Consider what you want to accomplish with the database. Will you be performing a lot of inserts to a single table at very high rates? Or will you be performing reporting and analytical functions with the data?
2. Once you've determined the purpose of the database, define what data you need to store to perform whatever functions are necessary.
3. Normalize till it hurts. If you're performing transaction processing (the most common function for a database) then you'll want a highly normalized database structure. If you're performing analytical functions, then you'll want a more denormalized structure that doesn't have to rely on joins to generate report results.
4. Typically, if you've really normalized the structure till it hurts then you need to take your normalization back a step or two to have a data structure that will be both normalized and functional.
5. A normalized database is mostly pointless if you fail to use keys. Make certain that each table has a primary key defined. Don't use surrogate keys just cause its what you always see. Consider what natural keys might exist in any given table. Once you are certain that you have the right primary key for each table, then you need to define your foreign key references. Establishing explicit foreign key relationships rather than relying on implicit definition will give you a performance boost, provide integrity for your data, and self-document the database structure.
6. Look for other indexes that exist within your tables. Do you have a column or set of columns that you will search against frequently like a username and password field? Indexes can be on a single column or multiple columns so think about how you'll be querying for data and create indexes as necessary for values you'll query against.

Answer (score 1):

Agree that you should ensure that your data is properly indexed.

Apart from that, if you are worried about table size, you can always implement some type of data archival strategy to later down the line.

Don't worry too much about this until you see problems cropping up, and don't optimise prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

For optimal reading you should have an index. A table exists to hold the rows it was designed to contain. As the number of rows increases, the value of the index comes into play and reading remains brisk.

Answer (score 0):

Phrased as such I don't know how to answer this question.  An idexed table of 100,000 records is faster than an unindexed table of 1,000.

What are your requirements?  How much data do you have?  Once you know the answer to these questions you can make decisions about indexing and/or partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very loose question, so a very loose answer :-)

In general if you do the basics - reasonable normalization, a sensible primary key and run-of-the-mill queries - then on today's hardware you'll get away with most things on a small to medium sized database - i.e. one with the largest table having less than 50,000 records.

However once you get past the 50k - 100k rows, which roughly corresponds to the point when the rdbms is likely to be memory constrained - then unless you have your access paths set up correctly (i.e. indexes) then performance will start to fall off catastrophically.  That is in the mathematical sense - in such scenario's it's not unusual to see performance deteriorate by an order of magnitude or two for a doubling in table size.

Obviously therefore the critical table size at which you need to pay attention will vary depending upon row size, machine memory, activity and other environmental issues, so there is no single answer, but it is well to be aware that performance generally does not degrade gracefully with table size and plan accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have to disagree with Cruachan about "50k - 100k rows .... roughly correspond(ing) to the point when the rdbms is likely to be memory constrained".  This blanket statement is just misleading without two additional data: approx. size of the row, and available memory.  I'm currently developing a database to find the longest common subsequence (a la bio-informatics) of lines within source code files, and reached millions of rows in one table, even with a VARCHAR field of close to 1000, before it became memory constrained.  So, with proper indexing, and sufficient RAM (a Gig or two), as regards the original question, with rows of 75 bytes at most, there is no reason why the proposed table couldn't hold tens of millions of records.

Answer (score 0):

The proper amount of data is a function of your application, not of the database. There are very few cases where a MySQL problem is solved by breaking a table into multiple subtables, if that's the intent of your question.

If you have a particular situation where queries are slow, it would probably be more useful to discuss how to improve that situation by modifying query or the table design.